# Map an object to a KeyValuePair

Tags: c#, list, reflection, key-value

I want to take one object and, using reflection, map the class properties to a `KeyValuePair` of `String`, `String`.

It is not that simple, though, since the class has some subclasses, and the subclass could have a subclass too..

My idea is end with a List of `KeyValuePair` that map the object with the subclasses.

Something like this:

```
List{
KeyValuePair -> (ObjectThing.FirstPropName, "4"),
KeyValuePair -> (ObjectThing.SecondPropName, "lol"),
KeyValuePair -> (ObjectThing.FirstPropName.FirstSubPropertyName, "3"),
KeyValuePair -> (ObjectThing.FirstPropName.SecondSubPropName, "10")
}
```

Comment: You might want to look into serialization.  Or providing enough detail in your question to make answering it possible.

Comment: you can use json serialization, or reflect the object's properties recursively , and transform to your custom format. Any detail for what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually do it like this

```
    public class Node
    {
        public Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        public List<Node> children = new List<Node>();
    }
```

Comment: My approach was to serialize to xml. Thank you